How to break up/ insert white spaces in geom_ribbon (R, ggplot)
I am trying to segment ggplot geom_ribbon fill based on a column ("type"). But type in my dataset alternates, and I can't figure out how to get ggplot to not make a continuous ribbon between the types.
I want to end up with something like this:

But I keep getting this:

For whatever reason, it seems to work fine and dandy if the type does not alternate. I'm really hoping there is a solution out there that doesn't involve carving my large dataset into tiny dfs

I've tried every version of group and scale_fill that I can imagine. I've also tried putting the colors as a column in the df, but to no avail. Help!
df = data.frame(
  type = c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b"),
  xdat = seq(1, 8),
  ydat = c(5,6,8,9,6,7,9,10)
)

type_colors = c("yellow", "blue")

ggplot(df, aes(x = xdat, y = ydat, ymin = ydat - 1, ymax = ydat + 1, fill = type) ) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(fill = factor(type))) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = type_colors, guide = "none") +
geom_line()


If we add dplyr to the mix, we can use consecutive_id to make a proper grouping variable. For example
df %>% 
  mutate(run = consecutive_id(type)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = xdat, y = ydat, ymin = ydat - 1, ymax = ydat + 1, fill = type) ) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(fill = factor(type), group=run)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = type_colors, guide = "none") +
    geom_line(aes(group=1))

Which returns


Ah nice, consecutive_id() is new to me.

I want to cry with happiness.  consecutive_id... I've had to do soooo much gnarly coding to do what this function does. Thanks @MrFlick, you always have such great suggestions!

Use the group aesthetic to define which parts of your geoms should be connected, e.g. using dplyr:
df = data.frame(
  type = c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b","b"),
  xdat = seq(1, 8),
  ydat = c(5,6,8,9,6,7,9,10)
) |> 
  mutate(group = cumsum(type != lag(type, default = last(type))))

ggplot(df, aes(x = xdat, y = ydat, ymin = ydat - 1, ymax = ydat + 1, fill = type) ) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = factor(type), group = group)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = type_colors, guide = "none")

